# Open up a ABPersonViewController from an APContact

Tags: ios, abaddressbook

I am using [APAddressBook](https://github.com/Alterplay/APAddressBook) which helps me use the address book in a simple way. Yes I know the Contacts and ContactsUI frameworks are there now, but they are iOS9+ and I also want to support iOS8.

The problem I have with it however, is that it only gives me a recordID as an `Int` to identify a contact. I now want to open up a `ABPersonViewController` to view the details of a contact. I need an `ABRecord` to do this. I tried to work out something myself and this is the result, which gives me a `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` error.

```
let apContact: APContact = ...

let recordId = ABRecordID(apContact.recordID.intValue)
let ab = ABAddressBookCreateWithOptions(nil, nil).takeRetainedValue()
let abRecord = ABAddressBookGetPersonWithRecordID(ab, recordId).takeRetainedValue()

let controller = ABPersonViewController()
controller.displayedPerson = abRecord
navigationController?.pushViewController(controller, animated: true)
```

Any suggestions on how to do it the proper way are welcome!

Comment: I found out the problem lies in the fact that I don't really understand how to use Unmanaged<T> properly, which is returned by those AB* functions.

Comment: If I do takeUnretainedValue() instead of takeRetainedValue() it solves my problem. But does this cause a memory leak?